# How can I implement Microsoft Azure (MFA) login authentication in an Electron application developed in React.js?

Tags: reactjs, electron, extension-methods, electron-builder, electron-packager

We have a React.js application that is running in Electron for desktop use. We have implemented Microsoft Azure AD for login authentication, which works fine in our React.js app. However, we are facing issues when trying to use it in our Electron application.
Electron uses an inbuilt Chromium browser to run the application. Our app requires opening i-frames in ServiceNow that require URL cookies for authentication. We are able to open the i-frames in our React.js application, as it runs in a browser that has an extension that provides the required cookies. However, we don't have that extension in our Electron application. We tried adding the extension to our Electron app, but ran into version issues since the Chrome version used by the system and Electron are different.

How can we access the credentials of the system's Chrome browser in our Electron application's browser? Is there a way to implement the Windows account extension in our Electron application without any version issues?
how to integrate windows account extension in electron?
What are the other way to include this feature in electron app...login with windows accounts seamlessly?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.